# How to validate 3 fields in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to validate 3 fileds

1. First name text box
2. Last name text box
3. Middle name text box

here is my code:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
    var z=document.forms["myForm"]["mname"].value;
    if(((x!='') && (y=='' && z==''))
          || ((y!='') && (x=='' && z==''))
          || ((z!='') && (x=='' && y=='')))
    {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    alert("fill input filed");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

My code is executing like this: if i wont enter anything in any field - alerting, this part is fine. Then when i enter one of the field its alerting me the if part same way if i will enter two text box my if part should be executed, but its not happening.

Can you change that condition please so that if I will fill 2 fields it should alert me at least one field can be filled?

Comment: Please rephrase and write meaningfully.

Comment: It's hard to understand what conditions you want to test for and what actions you want to take for each combination of test results. Perhaps you could edit your question and express the desired behavior as a table.

Comment: if i will enter 2 field it should alert me if part...only i.e First name must be filled out

Comment: [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/) may be of some use to you.

Comment: my Condition is like ...in the above code if i wont enter anything in the field its alerting me else part its fine..but my condition should work like if i will enter 2 field it should alert me if part...

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple, your first name is mandatory, so make it first priority

```
if(x==''){
    alert("First name must be filled out");return false;
    if(y=='' && z==''){
    //alert();// other condtions
    }
}else{
    alert("fill input filed");return false;
}
```

Comment: paste here what u have written

Comment: if((x!='') && (y=="" && z==""))
{
    alert("check name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
else if((y!='') && (x=="" && z==""))
{
    alert("cash name is empty");
    return false;
}
else if((z!='') && (x=="" && y==""))
{
    alert("test name is empty");
    return false;
}else{
alert("testing");
return true;
}

Comment: I have rewrite this condition, try it and let me know --- if(x!=''){
 if(y=='' && z=='')
  return false;
 else
  return true;
}else{
 // x='' for sure
 if(y=='' && z=='')
  return false;
 else if(y=='' && z!='')
  return true;
 else if(y!='' && z=='')
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}......put the alert before return false;

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for...

**Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname").value;
var y=document.getElementById("mname").value;
var z=document.getElementById("lname").value;

if((x==''))
{
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
else if((y==''))
{
    alert("Middle name is empty");
    return false;
}
else if((z==''))
{
    alert("Last name is empty");
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="#">
    <input type ="text" id ="fname"></input>
    <input type ="text" id ="mname"></input>
    <input type ="text" id ="lname"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validateForm();">
</form>
```

Comment: function validateForm()
    {

    var x=document.forms["add_new_report"]["cheque"].value;
    var y=document.forms["add_new_report"]["cash"].value;
    var z=document.forms["add_new_report"]["test"].value;

if((x!='') && (y=="" && z==""))
{
    alert("check name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
else if((y!='') && (x=="" && z==""))
{
    alert("cash name is empty");
    return false;
}
else if((z!='') && (x=="" && y==""))
{
    alert("test name is empty");
    return false;
}else{
alert("testing");
return true;
}
}